# Google Sheets - How to round SUMs across several cells once a number limit is reached

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Let me start by sharing the spreadsheet I want to update:
-redacted, since the issue is resolved now!-

You'll notice on the right there's a counter for "Total profit earned" showing Gems, Gold, Silver, then Copper. Currently, I have them auto-populated via `SUM` of the related columns to the left. What I'd like to see is:

- When Copper goes above 999 in value, Silver is increased by 1, adding to the existing value there.
- When Silver goes above 999 in value, Gold is increased by 1, adding to the existing value.
- When Gold goes above 99 (yes 99, not 999 this time), Gem is increased by 1, adding to the existing value
- A gem can stay as is and has no cap, it just needs to increase from Gold going over 99 each time.

How can I get the fields automatically updating once they hit these thresholds? I still need all of the data to be pulled from the columns on the left automatically. I'm a bit of a novice with spreadsheets so please spell this out for me as easily as you can.

EDIT: I tried the first proposed solution, however, I'd prefer to keep each currency type separate. Please consider that in your proposal.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question so that we can help you better. Thanks!

Comment: I've only tried that dude's first solution. I don't have enough knowledge to even attempt this on my own to begin with. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
={SUM(E3:E)+
  QUOTIENT(SUM(F3:F), 100)+
  QUOTIENT(MOD(SUM(F3:F), 100)+
  QUOTIENT(SUM(G3:G), 1000)+
  QUOTIENT(MOD(SUM(G3:G), 1000)+
  QUOTIENT(SUM(H3:H), 1000),1000),100),
  MOD(MOD(SUM(F3:F), 100)+
  QUOTIENT(SUM(G3:G), 1000)+
  QUOTIENT(MOD(SUM(G3:G), 1000)+
  QUOTIENT(SUM(H3:H), 1000),1000),100),
  MOD(MOD(SUM(G3:G), 1000)+
  QUOTIENT(SUM(H3:H), 1000),1000),
  MOD(SUM(H3:H), 1000)}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use one number instead and calculate all these currencies from it?

For instance you can have number 4,202,754 and it will populate copper with 754, silver with 202, gold with 4 and gems with 0.

For instance, we will store this number in B2.
For copper we'll use C2 field with this value:
    =MOD(B2, 1000)
For silver we'll use D2 field with this value:
    =MOD(FLOOR(B2 / 1000, 1), 1000)
For gold we'll use D2 field with this value:
    =MOD(FLOOR(B2 / 1000000, 1), 1000)
For gems we'll use D2 field with this value:
    =FLOOR(B2 / 1000000000, 1)

Comment: Well this does work, I appreciate it and can definitely use this if it comes down to it. However I'd still prefer to have each currency field separated, it makes more sense based on how the game we're referencing displays currency. Any ideas on how that can be leveraged? Or does having them separated out like that make this problem a billion times more complicated?

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE({
 TEXT(IFERROR(IF(LEN(SUM(H3:H))=8, 0, LEFT(SUM(H3:H), LEN(SUM(H3:H))-8)), 0)+
      IFERROR(IF(LEN(SUM(G3:G))=5, 0, LEFT(SUM(G3:G), LEN(SUM(G3:G))-5)), 0)+
      IFERROR(IF(LEN(SUM(F3:F))=2, 0, LEFT(SUM(F3:F), LEN(SUM(F3:F))-2)), 0)+
      SUM(E2:E), "#0"),
 TEXT(IFERROR(IF(LEN(SUM(H3:H))=6, 0, RIGHT(LEFT(SUM(H3:H), LEN(SUM(H3:H))-6), 2)), 0)+
      IFERROR(IF(LEN(SUM(G3:G))=3, 0, RIGHT(LEFT(SUM(G3:G), LEN(SUM(G3:G))-3), 2)), 0)+
      RIGHT(SUM(F3:F), 2), "#0"),
 TEXT(IFERROR(IF(LEN(SUM(H3:H))=3, 0, RIGHT(LEFT(SUM(H3:H), LEN(SUM(H3:H))-3), 3)), 0)+
      RIGHT(SUM(G3:G), 3), "#0"),
 TEXT(RIGHT(SUM(H3:H), 3), "#0")}))
```

[image: 0]